# Softwares to do a simple electrical project to a house

Tags: software

Hy guys,

I need to do a simple electrical project to a house.

I need make the plant, first of all, of course.
And then the electrical part.

I used the Google and I have some doubts.
All tips say that I should use AutoCad, it's really the only program I can use to do that?
Besides that, to do the electrical part, the tips always say I should use a plug-in to AutoCad.
Is there this only way? AutoCad + an auxiliary program to the electrial part?

The discipline I am doing is basic/just conceitual, I don't need a complex program, then a I would like to know whats the best software/way to do a simple electrical project to a house.

In resume, some  tips about which software is best to a begginer to apply that.

I am a begginer trying to do that. My first time.
Any tip is welcome.
:)

Thanks,

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design!

Comment: I've done plenty of electrical projects without any software at all being involved.

Comment: This is off-topic for here.  You might ask on diy.stackexchange.com, but if you do, please explain clearly why you need software for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Any 2D drawing package will probably do what you want.
 The are many free ones (most 2D, some 3D).

Electrical add ons are of possible use but need to be discssed once you know what's available.

[Wikipedia [list of available drawing software(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer-aided_design_editors) 2D and 3D. Says if free of gives cost and lists basic capabilities.

[FREE](http://sagcad.sourceforge.jp/en/overview.html) Sourceforge - SAG CAD

[FREE](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/free-cad/index.php?title=Main_Page) Sourceforge - FREE CAD ****3D****
 [FREE CAD links - useful](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/free-cad/index.php?title=Interesting_links)

[FREE](http://javacad.sourceforge.net/) Sourceforge - JCAD

Answer (score 2):

In my last projects I used the freely available [SketchUp](http://sketchup.google.com) to model my casings. Maybe you will find it useful for your purposes, too.

It is not exclusively for electrics, but a general purpose 3D sketching tool. I think the roots of the software lie in architecture.